# Capybara: method 'page' not working for a created module

Tags: selenium, capybara

I am using Cucumber with Selenium webdriver, Ruby 2.0.

When I use simple def's everything is ok, but when I tried to create module

```
module ELEM_TEXT_CONVERTING

  def self.convert(element1, element2)
    element1_blink = human2selector(element1)
    element2_blink = human2selector(element2)

    blink_bckgr(element1_blink, element2_blink)
    ...
end
```

where blink_bckgr launches the following script

```
page.execute_script <<-EOS
    var color_orig1 = document.querySelector('#{elem1}').style.backgroundColor;
    var color_orig2 = document.querySelector('#{elem2}').style.backgroundColor;
    window.color_orig1 = color_orig1;
    window.color_orig2 = color_orig2;
    document.querySelector('#{elem1}').style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    document.querySelector('#{elem2}').style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
  EOS
```

Finally I get an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `page' for ELEM_TEXT_CONVERTING:Module
./features/step_definitions/<...>.rb:22:in `blink_bckgr'
```

What is the trick here? Do I need to put some 'require's of standard libs inside a new module or what? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Require the .rb that you are initialising capybara on, in rspec you usually place it in spec_helper etc...

Then once you have that required you don't even need page... you should be able to call execute_script directly...

Something you can do to make sure the problem is the lack of visibility of capybara's instance is by calling something like the below:

```
Capybara.page.execute_script
```

if that works then the suggestion above solves your issue.